# Private SSH key from environment keeps asking for passphrase

Tags: shell, docker, ssh

I've got a container configuration which sets the SSH private key as environment variable (which comes from the system). Within the container I want to `rsync` some files to a remote server, but I keep getting asked for a passphrase.

The shell script for my container (without any overhead):

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh
ssh-keyscan <remote_server> >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts

echo $deploy_key >> "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
chmod 600 "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

ssh -i "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" <user>@<remote_server>
```

If I simply create an `id_rsa` file manually use this instead of the generated `id_rsa` everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in how the `id_rsa` file was created;

```
echo "${deploy_key}" >> "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Fixed the problem.